# BancBox SOAP API getClient - call fails using WCF client infrastructure

Tags: soap, xml-serialization, wcf-client, payment-processing

I apologize in advance if this post feels too long.  But 1) this is my first post ever and 2) I have really been over the river and through the woods trying to figure this out.

The Add Service Reference feature in Visual Studio 2012 produces a proxy that (apparently) generates invalid SOAP messages.  I suspect it has to do with serialization or how the proxy types are decorated but I cannot seem to figure it out.  Help is much appreciated.

**Detail 1.**  My environment is Visual Studio 2012 and I have created a .NET 4.5 class library with a service reference to **https://sandbox-api.bancbox.com/v1/BBXPort?wsdl**.  I'm attempting to call the getClient() function; which is defined here. (http://www.bancbox.com/api/view/45)

The code looks like this:

```
public void GetClient()

{
    // create an instance of the service reference proxy class
    var bbx=newBBXClient();
    bbx.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove<System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials>();
    bbx.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new CustomCredentials());

    bbx.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName="MY_USERNAME";
    bbx.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password="MY_PASSWORD";

    var customerId=newid {
            subscriberReferenceId="44XX33YY"
    };

    var request=newgetClientRequest {
            subscriberId=MY_SUBSCRIBER_ID,
            clientId=customerId
    };

    var response=bbx.getClient(request);
}
```

**Detail 2.**  I have made many successful calls into the web service via SoapUI.  The successful SoapUI-produced SOAP messages look like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:sch="schema.bancbox.com" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-11">
            <wsse:Username>MY_USERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">MY_PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">tRLo6AlRKl+/rULiKq6A6g==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2013-02-22T18:32:02.204Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <sch:getClient>
        <getClientRequest>
            <subscriberId>MY_SUBSCRIBER_ID</subscriberId>
                <clientId>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <subscriberReferenceId>44XX33YY</subscriberReferenceId>
                </clientId>
        </getClientRequest>
    </sch:getClient>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Detail 3.** Per Fiddler, my failed SOAP messages look like this

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPozcAgEH0QhJHloqMBWUf3mAAAAAA5wy3enJkDUGU8IaMUCFyEjzfL+1Uez1HhAvEeFpJ+30ACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-6e1c9f81-0651-41f7-b659-26b191bf7e13-1" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <o:Username>MY_USERNAME</o:Username>
            <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">MY_PASSWORD</o:Password>
            <o:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">hGggJkxurSkHQ3MKoeBK6AmEHNs=</o:Nonce>
            <u:Created>2013-02-23T11:24:47.663Z</u:Created>
        </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <getClient xmlns="schema.bancbox.com">
        <getClientRequest xmlns="">
            <subscriberId>MY_SUBSCRIBER_ID</subscriberId>
            <clientId>
                <subscriberReferenceId>XX55YY22</subscriberReferenceId>
            </clientId>
        </getClientRequest>
    </getClient>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The SOAP message above is produced when running the GetClient() method.  GetClient throws the following Exception.

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException
Unmarshalling Error: cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'getClientRequest' to a type definition for element 'getClientRequest'.
```

When I replay the same failing message using SoapUI, I get the following response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'getClientRequest' to a type definition for element 'getClientRequest'. </faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Detail 4.** Based on my research, this indicates that the server on the other end is Apache CXS.  It's choking on my SOAP request.  So I started playing around with my SOAP message and submitting it via SoapUI.

The first glaring distance in the successful message and my fail message are these lines

SUCCESS

```
<sch:getClient>
    <getClientRequest>
```

FAIL

```
<getClient xmlns="schema.bancbox.com">
    <getClientRequest xmlns="">
```

So the first thing that I did was make my getClientRequest tag identical to the successful one.

```
<getClient xmlns="schema.bancbox.com">
    <getClientRequest>
```

This produced the following response.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Found element {schema.bancbox.com}getClientRequest but could not find matching RPC/Literal part</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The next thing that I did is change the way the getClient tag is assigned a schema.

BEFORE

```
<getClient xmlns="schema.bancbox.com">
```

AFTER

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:bb="schema.bancbox.com" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
. . .
    <bb:getClient>
        <getClientRequest>
. . .
    </bb:getClient>
```

The resultant SOAP message looks like this and it is successful.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:bb="schema.bancbox.com" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPozcAgEH0QhJHloqMBWUf3mAAAAAA5wy3enJkDUGU8IaMUCFyEjzfL+1Uez1HhAvEeFpJ+30ACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-6e1c9f81-0651-41f7-b659-26b191bf7e13-1" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <o:Username>MY_USERNAME</o:Username>
            <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">MY_PASSWORD</o:Password>
            <o:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">hGggJkxurSkHQ3MKoeBK6AmEHNs=</o:Nonce>
            <u:Created>2013-02-23T11:24:47.663Z</u:Created>
        </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <bb:getClient>
        <getClientRequest>
            <subscriberId>MY_SUBSCRIBER_ID</subscriberId>
            <clientId>
                <subscriberReferenceId>XX55YY22</subscriberReferenceId>
            </clientId>
        </getClientRequest>
    </bb:getClient>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

So the million dollar questions are WHY and HOW.

*WHY does the .NET proxy class serialize the SOAP message the way it does?

*HOW do I fix it?  How can I may my proxy serialize into the SOAP message above? How can I force the serializer to define shorthand for the message namespace in the Envelop and then use the shorthand in the message tag?

FYI, to even get to this point I had to get past a number of WCF WSE issues and ended up implementing the solution so generously provided on Rich Stahls blog.  I would post the link but apparently I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From I understand, the SOAP message that WCF produces is syntactically correct.  However, Java CXF web services are very rigid with regards to the SOAP messages that they will accept.

The solution to specific problem setting aliases for xml namespace definitions in the Operation node of the SOAP messages produced by WCF proxies involves implementing a **Custom Message Inspector** is detailed here:  [Force WCF to create an xml namespace alias in client proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056340/force-wcf-to-create-an-xml-namespace-alias-in-client-proxy/15070956#15070956).

This has completely resolved my issue.